# Vaadin 14 Springboot javascript does not work

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I'm trying to develop my first Vaadin 14 application, I'm also using Spring boot framework for it.
I've created a javascript file, I put it into the folder frontend/src with the name of teams.js and I'm trying to import it with `@JsModule("src/teams.js")`. My root view class looks like this:

```
@Route("")
@PageTitle("Teams organization store init")
@Slf4j
@JsModule("src/teams.js")
@Tag("TeamsEntry")
public class TeamsEntryView extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver {

    public TeamsEntryView() {
        initTeams();
    }

    private void initTeams() {
        var ui = UI.getCurrent();
        var page = ui.getPage();
        log.info("Teams initialization...");
        page.executeJs(getTeamsConfig()).toCompletableFuture().whenComplete(((jsonValue, throwable) ->
                log.info("Teams initialization completed: {} with throwable {}", jsonValue.toJson(), throwable.getMessage())
        ));

    }

    private String getTeamsConfig() {
        return """
                console.log('ss');
                window.initTeams();
                console.log('xx');
                return true;
                """;
    }
...
```

My js file looks like this:

```
window = {
    initTeams: function () {
        console.log('initTeams...');
    }
}
```

In this case, I see "ss" in the browser's console, but nothing more.
If I remove the `window.initTeams();` line I get "ss" and "xx" as well.
If I declare a simple function in the js file and call it without the "window" class I get similar results.
If I use `@Javascript` or `page.addJavascript("src/teams.js")` I get this error when the page loads: "> unexpected character"
If I try to call `join()` or `get()` on the completable future the browser freeze.
If I use `@Javascript("frontend://src/teams.js")` I get some CORS error like if it is trying to download something from the "frontend" host.
I've tried to put the `@JsModule` on a component instead of my view.. it does not work.
I've tried to put my js file to the root, and to the resources folder.

I could not find any other solution to import and use my js file into vaadin14 with spring boot.
Also, I'm not sure why the browser freeze if I call "join()" on completable future, and also the on the result of it sentToBrowser returns false even if I see the console logs in the browsers log...

Can somebody explain to me how should I do the javascript import, why my current code does not work, and why the "join()" freezes the browser, please?

Thank you in advance!

@Edit

I have also tried with this annotation `@JavaScript("./src/teams.js")` and a js like this:

```
    function initTeams () {  
        console.log('initTeams...');  
        console.log("Teams initialized!")  
    }
```

@Edit

Okay so finally I got it working.
The js file has to be under `root/src/main/webapp/src` folder.
Nor `@JavaScript` and nor the `@JsModule` worked for me, so I had to import my js file as:

```
        var ui = UI.getCurrent();
        var page = ui.getPage();
        page.addJavaScript("src/teams.js");
```

Then I can call it like `window.initTeams()` or like `initTeams()` and both works fine. Altough the completable future below still never executes, and `isSentToBrowser()` always returns false.

```
page.executeJs(getTeamsConfig()).toCompletableFuture().whenComplete(((jsonValue, throwable) ->
                log.info("Teams initialization completed: {} with throwable {}", jsonValue.toJson(), throwable.getMessage())
        ));
```

I must mention if I start the path with '.' like `page.addJavaScript(".src/teams.js");` then it does not find the file.

Does anybody have an answer, why the completable future never executes?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the following code redefines the `window` object:

> ```js
> window = {
>     initTeams: function () {
>         console.log('initTeams...');
>     }
> }
> ```

Did you meant to add a function to the `window` object? Like so:

```js
window.initTeams = function () {
    console.log('initTeams...');
};
```

If you want to keep code visually similar to yours:

```js
window = {
    ...window,
    {
        initTeams: function() {
            console.log('initTeams...');
        }
    }
}
```

Other options:

```js
window['initTeams'] = function() {...}
Object.assign(window, {initTeams: function() {...}})
Object.defineProperty(window, 'initTeams', {value: function() {console.log('foo')}});
```

*Gotta love JavaScript...*

Also, for more knowledge, the code mentioned in your @Edit section could not be called. Calling `initTeams()` is equivalent to `window.initTeams()`. The function must exist in the `window` object. This is why, for example, you see some custom elements defined like `customElements.define(...)` and `window.customElements.define(...)`.

Comment: Clarification for the last part. In a "regular" JS file, unqualified `function` definitions are added to `window`. But this is not the case when a JS file is loaded as an ES module.

Comment: I have changed my js file content to

 window.initTeams = function () {
    console.log('initTeams...');
};

and have tried to import it like `@JavaScript("./src/teams.js")` and `@JsModule("./src/teams.js")` I have put the file to `root/frontend/src/teams.js` and to `resources/src/teams.js` and also to `resources/static/src/teams.js` and I tried to invoke it as `window.initTeams()` and `initTeams()`... none of this worked... I'm not sure which one is the correct in case of vaadin14, and what I'm doing wrong..